# Replace = with equals in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I want to replace = with equals for Integer object

```
      public boolean isResult(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d){
        return a + b!= c + d
```

I tried

```
 Integer res1 = a + b
 Integer res 2 = c + d

if(!res1.equals(res2)){
    return;
 }
```

Is there a way to minimize the code rather than again assigning to an object.

Comment: `return !res1.equals(res2);`

Comment: At this point you should consider primitive datatype `int` and use == to compare. I don‘t see any benefit in using Integer and .equals to do a mathematical comparison.

`(a + b) != (c + d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean isResult(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d) {
    
    if (!Optional.of(a+b).equals(Optional.of(c+d))){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use Optional İf you don't want to use res1 and res2